# UnifiAP s not updating

Tags: wireless-access-point

Bought a unifi cloudKey recently but it is insisting that I update the unifi access points before it will adopt them. But the updating always fails. They are all on the same network and reset. the only error message once was target not correct. The model of the access points is UnifiAP nothing else. have tried to update them manually with the url, using the discover ap but not sure which update to download. Any help deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find new firmware [here](https://www.ui.com/download/unifi/unifi-ap). You want the link labelled "for UAP, UAP-LR, UAP-OD, UAP-OD5". This is a very old access point that is 2.4GHz only and only supports 802.11n.

As of right now, the latest non-beta release is 4.0.15 and the direct download link is: https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/firmware/BZ2/4.0.15.9872/BZ.ar7240.v4.0.15.9872.181229.0259.bin